# Change default XcomArg key in custom operators

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a bunch of custom operators and I wanted to try to make use of XcomArg and using .output in my tasks.

For example, below I commented out the `xcom_push` to return the list:

```
def execute(self, context):
    # context["ti"].xcom_push(key="extract_list", value=extract_list)
    return extract_list
```

The issue is that my key has historically been "extract_list" and I have some references to that key elsewhere. And I pass other xcoms (such as maximum ID/timestamp) and those xcoms are labeled as `return_value`.

Can I change the key of an xcom that I push?

This snippet works, but the key is `return_value`:

```
    extract = FileToAzureBlobOperator(
        task_id="extract-test",
        remote_directories=["/input/test"],
        subfolders=["test", "raw"],
        params={
            "start": "{{ data_interval_start }}",
            "end": "{{ data_interval_end }}",
        },
    )

    transform = PrepareParquetOperator(
        task_id="transform-test",
        input_files=extract.output,
        output_folder="test/staging",
        custom_transform_script="scripts.common.test",
        partition_columns=["date_id"],
    )
```

I have tried adding `test = XComArg(operator=extract, key="test_key")` and then have the `input_files=test` in my transform task as well, but no luck. I think I need to overwrite the default key inside of my FileToAzureBlobOperator.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to return the value as dictionary to get what you want:

```
return {"extract_list": extract_list}
```

Comment: Hm, I tested that and it returned the return_value as the key still:

`return_value {'extract_list': ['test/20211123T161610.txt']}`

My expected output would be extact_list as the key and the list of blobs as the value:
`extract_list    ['test/20211123T161610.txt']`

Comment: How about also changing:
```
input_files=extract.output['extract_list']
```

Comment: Hm, the key is still "return_value" though, so it would require changes to my code in other places that use xcom.pull(key="extract_list"). Unfortunately, I have used a different key for each custom operator historically

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which worked using XComArg. It required changing my DAG file a bit.

```
    extract = FileToAzureBlobOperator(
        task_id="extract-test",
        remote_directories=["/input/test"],
        subfolders=["test", "raw"],
        params={
            "start": "{{ data_interval_start }}",
            "end": "{{ data_interval_end }}",
        },
    )

    extracted_files = XComArg(extract, "extract_list")

    transform = PrepareParquetOperator(
        task_id="transform",
        input_files=extracted_files,
    )

    transformed_files = XComArg(transform, "filter_list")

    finalize = DatasetToDatasetOperator(
        task_id="finalize",
        input_files=transformed_files,
    
    )

    extracted_files >> transformed_files >> finalize
```

Eventually my plan is to remove `xcom.push()` from my operators and just return the values directly so I can make use of `.output` without requiring the XComArg line. I just need to clean up references to the custom key names in other areas.